# Spring passing Class<?> through constructor from xml file

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is it possible to inject Class param through constructor from xml file? How is it done?
For example

```
public Server(Class<?>... configuration) {}
```

This is class with param to inject

This is my xml file

```
<constructor-arg index="0"></constructor-arg>
```

But what shall I do next?

Comment: Just provide the fully qualified class name in the constructor argument.

Comment: Dunno why that didn't work at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parameter was of type `Class<?>`, then all you would need is to provide the fully qualified class name

```
<constructor-arg index="0">java.lang.String</constructor-arg>
```

But since you have a varargs, you need to add an `<array>` with values

```
<constructor-arg index="0">
    <array>
        <value>
            java.lang.String
        </value>
    </array>
</constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score -1):

since args is an array of Object you can use :

```
<bean name="myBean" class="MyClass"> <constructor-arg> <list> <value>111</value> <value>222</value> <value>333</value> <value>444</value> </list> </constructor-arg> </bean>
```